# Parsing MySQL output in Bash

Tags: mysql, bash

How can I redirect output of mysql query with table border as separator?
I try with this code :

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -D cronjob -e "select * from cron_list" > query.txt
```

What I expect is output like :

```
| id |  datetime  | recurrency |          command          |
|  1 | 2014-10-10 |    daily   | bash /media/data/daily.sh |
|  2 | 2014-10-09 |  minutely  |           conky           |
```

But when I use that code, it give me output like

```
 id   datetime   recurrency           command          
  1  2014-10-10     daily    bash /media/data/daily.sh 
  2  2014-10-09   minutely             conky
```

So, how can I redirect the output from terminal into file with separator like in terminal?
Sorry for bad english

Comment: Try using `-t` parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man mysql`:

> **--table, -t**
>
> Display output in table format. This is the default for interactive
>   use, but can be used to produce table output in batch mode.

Note `-t` is the default behaviour, but not whenever you pipe to a file. That's why in that case you have to make it explicit.

---

Other interesting options, for other kind of outputs:

> **--silent, -s**
>
> Silent mode. Produce less output. This option can be given multiple
>   times to produce less and less output.
>
> This option results in nontabular output format and escaping of
>   special characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see
>   the description for the --raw option.
>
> **--skip-column-names**, -N
>
> Do not write column names in results.
>
> **--html, -H**
>
> Produce HTML output.

Comment: I don't know, when I didn't include `-t` parameter. It give me output like `--silent`. By the way, thanks for explanation :)

Comment: I have been looking for information of default settings but I cannot find anywhere that sets these defaults. Just guessing: maybe you have an alias?

Comment: *"...produce table output in batch mode"* appears to mean "whenever `STDOUT` is not a tty," as is the case with `>` redirection to a file.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot excellent! This seems to answer the question.